# Resolving relative template urls with angularJS and asp.net MVC

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, asp.net-mvc-5

I searched through many posts already, but still can't make run a very basic custom directive since the `templateUrl` is not resolved correctly.

I've got an `AngularJSController` with an Index - action (asp.net MVC), calling View/AngularJS/Index.cshtml, very basic. In there, I call a custom directive:

```
<product-title></product-title>
```

which is outlined liked that:

```
    app.directive('productTitle', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            // ends up with wrong url '{root-path}/AngularJS/AngularJSTemplates/ProductTitle'
            templateUrl: 'AngularJSTemplates/ProductTitle'
        }
    });
```

As you can see, it should call the controller `AngularJSTemplatesController` (asp.net MVC) with the action method `ProductTitle`. This will return my partial for angularJS. **And here is the problem:** AngularJS calls `{root-path}/AngularJS/AngularJSTemplates/ProductTitle` instead of `{root-path}/AngularJSTemplates/ProductTitle`...

What I am missing here? Do I really need to define the root-path somewhere as a javascript-global and use it for absolute paths?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to define the base url, see the documentation on using Relative links [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Answer (score -2):

just replace directive with follwing directive :

```
app.directive('productTitle', function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            // ends up with wrong url '{root-path}/AngularJS/AngularJSTemplates/ProductTitle'
            templateUrl: 'AngularJS/AngularJSTemplates/ProductTitle'
        }
    });
```

i think directive cant find your template. `AngularJS/AngularJSTemplates/ProductTitle` is the relative url for your template. i think it wil work.